# How can I create a dynamic src url in html img tag?

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2, dynamic-url

```
<img src="https://openweathermap.org/img/wn/10d@2x.png">
```

The src url changes dynamically by changing the last part
for example, by changing 10d@2x.png to 11d@2x.png a different icon can be obtained.
However, I want to dynamically change the url in html using Jinja2 and flask

I tried using

```
img src="https://openweathermap.org/img/wn/{{icon}}@2x.png"
```

and send the icon variable from server side, but it won't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `render_template` in your code, do something like that:

```
return render_template('mytemplate.html', icon='11d')
```

In your template:

```
<img src="https://openweathermap.org/img/wn/{{ icon }}@2x.png">
```

Note the double-curly braces to render the variable. See the [documentation](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#variables)

Comment: I did try with double as well as single curly braces, but I'm unable to get the image from the url

Comment: If you copy/paste the generated url in your browser, does it work?

Comment: I created a test anchor tag using <a href="http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/{{icon}}@2x.png">test</a> and it is working , but the image tag is not showing the image at the url

Comment: How do you render your template?

Comment: return render_template("weather.html", filename = filename, city=city, current_temp= current_temp, current_weather= current_weather,hi_low= hi_low, icon ='13d' )

Comment: Hey i found the bug . there was an extra d in src which was causing the issue, Thanks a lot for helping!!

Comment: I accepted the answer as well as upvoted, thanks again!